# Sending SMS messages from a Rails Application without Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sms-gateway

What are the links/keys needed to create a ruby application to send an SMS using an API. Without having to write gems for it? I have a link to the service and an API key. I need to know where to start. Im new to ruby and am trying to follow this tutorial but cant seem to get anywhere without knowing what i do without using clickatell. http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/sending-sms-messages-from-your-rails-application.html

Comment: What service are you actually using? Would be helpful to know.

Comment: http://services.xxxx.com/SMS where xxxx stands for the company name. I dont know if i can write it on a common forum. however having said that its more or less like the company subscribed to a service provide r and have got this facility. they also have an api

Comment: Well, can you then provide some information about the API and how you can request it? Is it some kind of REST API?

Comment: Yes it is a REST API. The thing is i dont know how to request it. Maybe POST method?

Comment: That should be documented somewhere. Gonna answer that question with code examples, as I think you know what URL to hit and what data to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending the actual HTTP request, you can use one of the several ruby HTTP libraries/gems, like [REST Client](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client), [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or plain [Net/HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

The most simple one might be REST Client, example:

```
require 'rest_client'

API_URL = 'http://yourapiurl.com/resource'
API_KEY = 'thatoneapikey'

RestClient.post API_URL, :api_key => API_KEY, :number => '7812637813', :body => 'Foo SMS Text Bar Baz'
```

Best regards

Tobias

Comment: That hardly depends on your application. Are you using some kind of framework?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question from 20hours ago. The code above is an example of all that you need to use a (simple) REST API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem done by a friend for the routo messaging system

https://github.com/weboglobin/Routo

you can use it, or just take it as an inspiration

Comment: Hi just a question. Is this a gem i can use or is it an application?

Comment: it's a gem, but it not a very polish one, I mentioned it as an example, as you didn'y mentionned the service you want to use.